# Firebase childEventListener return value when path does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Reading the documentation, It seems childEventListener does not fire when the path does not exist.

This is a problem since I want to display a message to the user that there is no data.

I could add a valueEventListener like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530566/find-out-if-child-event-listener-on-firebase-completely-load-all-data) but I'm limiting the query to the latest value i.e query.limitToLast() and a valueEventListener doesn't limitTolast but gets all the data in the path.

Example, I have:

```
posts
{
    $userid
    {
        $postid {
            post_content:content
            timestamp:1234567
        }
        $postid {
            post_content:content
            timestamp:1234567
        }
        $postid {
            post_content:content
            timestamp:1234567
        }
        $postid {
            post_content:content
            timestamp:1234567
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only interested in the latest post so I do `firebaseRef.child(users).child(userid).limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener` but the user might not have posts yet and childEventListener does not fire in that case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean limiting a value listener. It will be a lot easier to help if you share the data model (as JSON text, no screenshots) and the code that you're struggling with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle both the children and the case where no children exists, you can add both a value and a child listener:

```
Query query = firebaseRef.child(users).child(userid).limitToLast(1);
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        ...
    }
    ...
});
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
            // TODO: handle the "no data available" scenario
        }
    });
});
```

The Firebase client is smart enough to only load data once, even if there are multiple listeners like in the above case.

---

If you want, you can also accomplish this with a single `ValueEventListener` like this:

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
            // TODO: handle the "no data available" scenario
        }
        else {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                // TODO: handle the child snapshot
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Since we now get all matching child nodes in `snapshot`, we loop over the `snapshot.getChildren()` to get the same data as in `onChildAdded`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same answer as the link I posted. Problem is it gets all the data in the node.

Comment: Since the initial query (I'll fix the code in a bit) is `limitToLast(1)` both listeners will initially get at most one callback.

Comment: I don't know why, but I was sure ValueEventListener was returning the whole node without limiting it to the last one...hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since its impossible to attach a listener to a non existing path, you could try adding a property to your user that sets the number of posts he has. Add a listener to that property and if it changes, then you are certain that indeed the user has a path reference in posts, then you can add a listener to that node and get the query every time a child is added with .childAdded .