# Firebase database not working with addChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase database and I'm retrieving data from it. When my database has data, addChildEventListener working well but when my database hasn't data, addChildEventListener not working. Bellow, this is my code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("music");

public void getListMusicFromFirebase() {
    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(this);
} 

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    updateMusic(dataSnapshot);
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    updateMusic(dataSnapshot);
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    updateMusic(dataSnapshot);
}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}

private void updateMusic(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    mListMusic.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String title = snapshot.getValue(Music.class).getTitle();
        String artist = snapshot.getValue(Music.class).getArtist();
        String year = snapshot.getValue(Music.class).getYear();
        String duration = snapshot.getValue(Music.class).getDuration();
        String uri = snapshot.getValue(Music.class).getUri();

        Music music = new Music(title, artist, year, duration, uri);
        mListMusic.add(music);
    }

    if (mListMusic.size() > 0) {
        bindingListMusic();
        return;
    }
    mBinding.tvDataEmpty.setText("No data");
    mDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I check my list. If size of it greater than 0, I will bind it to recyclerview and opposite, I will notify it haven't data, it working well when having data but when I delete all data from Firebase database, my code can't perform updateMusic() method.

Please help.

Comment: As Nishant said: child events will only fire *if* a child exists/existed. It is easiest to start your UI with the "zero state", so showing "no data found" from the start and then removing that as data comes in.

But if you want to handle the no-data case explicitly, you can attach an extra `ValueEvntListener` and use that to detect when there are no children. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671076/firebase-childeventlistener-return-value-when-path-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

To initiate your listener you should have the required data in your firebase database. AddChildEvent listener requires a predefined parent where you will attach it on app launch(or whenever you want) . If there is no parent the listener will never be attached or initiated.

This will result in no response when you later add a parent and add childs to it. So, always make sure that the parent to which you adding childEventListener is already present and the value is not null.

Hope this helps.